# Implement a for each loop in drools

Tags: java, grails, drools, drools-flow

I want to implement a loop that will check every object in the list "then" return a boolean value.

```
function boolean anyActiveUsers(Application app, String params){
    if(app.getApplicantType().toString() == params) {
        for ( User user: app.getUsers()){
            if(user.getStatus() == "ACTIVE")
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;
 }
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Function Compilation error
>   anyActiveUsers (line:7): File org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/drools/example/anyActiveUsers.java, Line 15, Column 25: Operator ";" expected

Can someone help me how to implement a for each loop in drools function?

Comment: You should not take the code from answer and update in the post. It will completely confuse the future readers.

Comment: Ok. sorry, but the real issue here is I'm not sure whether the drools supports a for each function or not .

Comment: if it's a java code, what keyword `function` does here?

Comment: This is a drools rule language

Comment: Need Application.java for reproducing the problem. And the Drools version.

Comment: The for statement in a function works fine in 6.3.0 - the error message seems to indicate that you've made some other typo or error. - See my previous comment.

Comment: @IgorArtamonov - `function` is a keyword in the Drools Rules Language (DRL), which essentially lets you write a block of Java code within a DRL file. The rest of that block follows the same rules as a Java method. Therefore, (as you may well have been thinking) testing string equality with `==` is highly unlikely to be appropriate. fwiw - DRL does have its own syntax for writing such tests, as shown in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547374/drools-mvel-for-each-element-in-a-map

Comment: @Steve What Steve (probably) means with the last sentence is that Drools lets you write `==` and `!=` for comparing String values, resulting in a call to `equals` behind the scenes, but *only in rule conditions*.

Comment: Indeed - that  is what I meant :)